# Rotating (Changing), centered, unstretched Background Image Script

Tags: javascript, image, background

I am trying to find a script that will allow me to have my background image on my website change and satisfy the following conditions:

- Stay centered
- NOT resize
- Not allow you to scroll around to see the whole thing (In other words, it has to act like a typical background, NOT an image)
- Fade in and out slowly, and go through several images and then restart

It seems like it's very easy to accomplish one or two of these things, but all of them together appear to be almost impossible... There are lots of implementations using that jQuery slide thing but they all either require you to have separate divs for each image, which then require you to specify a size in order to see the background image and thus allow you to scroll the screen around, OR, the image resizes to the whole window, which I also don't want, or it won't center.

[This tutorial](http://fearlessflyer.com/2011/10/create-rotating-full-paged-background-images-with-css-and-jquery/) has just what I'm looking for, *except* the image resizes to the window. That would seem like an added feature that would be more work to *have* than *not* to have, but I can't figure out how to get rid of it.

Anyway, if anyone knows of an existing resource with an example of what I am looking for that would be awesome, or maybe a small change to that one I shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

You can use the code from that tutorial, but change the css to be this:

```
#slideshow, img.bgM {
    width:1600px;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-400px;
    z-index:-9999;
}
```

The width is just however wide your bg images are, note that they are going to have to all be the same, otherwise they will grow to fit the width.

Position: fixed; will prevent scrolling from happening.

But to center it with fixed positioning, you have to do the left 50% part and then set the margin-left to be negative 1/4 of your image width. Why 1/4? I'm not really sure... 1/2 makes sense to me, and that's what many tutorials for centering fixed positioned elements say it should be, but for me it was 1/4. Weird!

Either way, it should work great. Hope this helps someone else!